# jmap: package not found in openjdk-debuginfo in Aws linux

Tags: java, sudo

I installed:

```
sudo yum --enablerepo='*-debug*' install java-1.8.0-openjdk-debuginfo
```

Then I ran this command:

```
sudo -u tomcat jmap -F -dump:format=b,file=/usr/tmp/heapdump.bin 27167
```

but error occurred:

```
 jmap: package not found in openjdk-debuginfo
```

Comment: set an evironment path for jmap in linux

Comment: thankyou for fast reply and i will try this but i can't find jmap so how can set jmap path in environment path

Comment: this is not duplicate question sir i cant found this answer that's why i ask